# My data doesn't save in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My data doesn't save in my database.
When I entering my data and click on the save button then go to the data folder and open my database I understand that my data doesn't save.
now I want to know what's the problem with my database
(I rooted my device)

box_2_dtent.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.box_2_dtent);
    contentHelper = new ContentHelper(box_2_dtent.this);
    final EditText cmpnm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_cmpnm);
    final EditText cmptl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_cmptel);
    final EditText arz = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_arz);
    final EditText bxcel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxcel);
    final EditText bxch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxch);
    final EditText bxclr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxclr);
    final EditText bxcst = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxcst);
    final EditText bxds = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxds);
    final EditText bxex = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxex);
    final EditText bxgh = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxgh);
    final EditText bxgl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxgl);
    final EditText bxkl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxkl);
    final EditText bxknd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxknd);
    final EditText bxmn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxmn);
    final EditText bxmove = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxmove);
    final EditText bxnum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxnum);
    final EditText bxzn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxzn);
    final EditText bxsd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxsd);
    final EditText tol = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_tol);
    final EditText ertefa = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_ertefa);
    final EditText date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_date);
    final EditText prjnm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_prjnm);
    final EditText bxps = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxps);
    final EditText bxpck = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.act_2_bxpck);
    final TextView percst = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.act_2_percst);
    final TextView finalcost = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.act_2_finalcost);
    Button btnres = (Button)findViewById(R.id.act_2_res);
    btnres.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            {
                content content = new content();
                content.cmpnm = cmpnm.getText().toString();
                content.tel = cmptl.getText().toString();
                content.arz = arz.getText().toString();
                content.cel = bxcel.getText().toString();
                content.chop = bxch.getText().toString();
                content.clr = bxclr.getText().toString();
                content.cost = bxcst.getText().toString();
                content.design = bxds.getText().toString();
                content.ext = bxex.getText().toString();
                content.gh = bxgh.getText().toString();
                content.gl = bxgl.getText().toString();
                content.kl = bxkl.getText().toString();
                content.bxknd = bxknd.getText().toString();
                content.mn = bxmn.getText().toString();
                content.move = bxmove.getText().toString();
                content.num = bxnum.getText().toString();
                content.zn = bxzn.getText().toString();
                content.profit = bxsd.getText().toString();
                content.tol = tol.getText().toString();
                content.ertefa = ertefa.getText().toString();
                content.date = date.getText().toString();
                content.prjnm = prjnm.getText().toString();
                content.pst = bxps.getText().toString();
                content.pack = bxpck.getText().toString();
                content.percost = percst.getText().toString();
                content.finalcost = finalcost.getText().toString();
                contentHelper.save(content);
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), getString(R.string.savedatecomplte), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cmpnm.setText("");
                cmptl.setText("");
                arz.setText("");
                bxcel.setText("");
                bxch.setText("");
                bxclr.setText("");
                bxcst.setText("");
                bxds.setText("");
                bxex.setText("");
                bxgh.setText("");
                bxgl.setText("");
                bxkl.setText("");
                bxknd.setText("");
                bxmn.setText("");
                bxmove.setText("");
                bxnum.setText("");
                bxzn.setText("");
                tol.setText("");
                ertefa.setText("");
                date.setText("");
                prjnm.setText("");
                bxps.setText("");
                bxpck.setText("");
                cmpnm.setText("");
                bxsd.setText("");

            }
        }
    });
```

content.java

```
package m_khalili.ir.boxmakingassistant;
public class content
{
Long id;
String cmpnm;
String bxknd;
String tol;
String arz;
String ertefa;
String cost;
String num;
String date;
String tel;
String design;
String zn;
String pst;
String chop;
String gl;
String mn;
String gh;
String kl,pack,move,ext,clr,cel,profit,finalcost,percost,prjnm;

}
```

ContentHelper.java

```
public class ContentHelper
{
dbhelper dbhelper;
public ContentHelper(Context context)
{
    dbhelper = new dbhelper(context);
}
public Long save(content content)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("cmpnm",content.cmpnm);
    contentValues.put("bxknd",content.bxknd);
    contentValues.put("tol",content.tol);
    contentValues.put("arz",content.arz);
    contentValues.put("ertefa",content.ertefa);
    contentValues.put("cost",content.cost);
    contentValues.put("num",content.num);
    contentValues.put("date",content.date);
    contentValues.put("tel",content.tel);
    contentValues.put("design",content.design);
    contentValues.put("zn",content.zn);
    contentValues.put("pst",content.pst);
    contentValues.put("chop",content.chop);
    contentValues.put("gl",content.gl);
    contentValues.put("mn",content.mn);
    contentValues.put("gh",content.gh);
    contentValues.put("kl",content.kl);
    contentValues.put("pack",content.pack);
    contentValues.put("move",content.move);
    contentValues.put("ext",content.ext);
    contentValues.put("clr",content.clr);
    contentValues.put("cel",content.cel);
    contentValues.put("profit",content.profit);
    contentValues.put("finalcost",content.finalcost);
    contentValues.put("percost",content.percost);
    contentValues.put("prjnm",content.prjnm);

    dbhelper.opendb();
    Long a = dbhelper.db.insert(m_khalili.ir.boxmakingassistant.dbhelper.content,null,contentValues);
    dbhelper.closedb();
    return a;
}
}
```

dbhelper.java

```
public class dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public static final String dbname = "datebase.db";
public static final int dbversion = 1;
public static final String content = "content";
SQLiteDatabase db;
public dbhelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, dbname, null, dbversion);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
{
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + content + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
            " cmpnm STRING, bxknd STRING, tol STRING NOT NULL, arz STRING NOT NULL, ertefa STRING NOT NULL," +
            " cost STRING NOT NULL, num STRING NOT NULL, date STRING, tell STRING, design STRING, zn STRING," +
            " pst STRING, chop STRING, gl STRING, mn STRING, gh STRING, kl STRING, pack STRING, move STRING," +
            " ext STRING, clr STRING, cel STRING, prf STRING, finalcost STRING, percost STRING, prjnm STRING)");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
}
public void opendb()
{
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}
public void closedb()
{
    if(db.isOpen())
    {
        db.close();
    }
}
}
```

I did this whit a tutorial

Comment: Replace `insert()` with `insertOrThrow()`.

Comment: **thank you for answering** but when I did this my application stop its working

Comment: Good! Now you have an error message that tells you what is wrong.

Comment: Its error is for these two lines {contentHelper.save(content);} & {Long a = dbhelper.db.insertOrThrow(m_khalili.ir.boxmakingassistant.dbhelper.content,null,contentValues);}

Comment: See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: **thank you very much**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issues are that some column names in ContentHelper.java do not match the respective column names in the definition of the table.

That is you would have got an error such as :-

```
08-18 23:05:11.449 1915-1915/so51893932.so51893932 E/SQLiteLog: (1) table content has no column named profit
08-18 23:05:11.450 1915-1915/so51893932.so51893932 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting cel=d ertefa=t finalcost=z profit=r tol=s mn=n gl=k kl=l prjnm=v num=p cost=g arz=c clr=f chop=e cmpnm=a gh=j date=u pst=w zn=q pack=x ext=i bxknd=m tel=b percost=y move=o design=h
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table content has no column named profit (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO content(cel,ertefa,finalcost,profit,tol,mn,gl,kl,prjnm,num,cost,arz,clr,chop,cmpnm,gh,date,pst,zn,pack,ext,bxknd,tel,percost,move,design) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at so51893932.so51893932.ContentHelper.save(ContentHelper.java:44)
        at so51893932.so51893932.box_2_dtent$1.onClick(box_2_dtent.java:78)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Fixing the above then results in :-

```
08-18 23:09:46.051 2003-2003/so51893932.so51893932 E/SQLiteLog: (1) table content has no column named tel
08-18 23:09:46.051 2003-2003/so51893932.so51893932 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting cel=d ertefa=t finalcost=z tol=s mn=n gl=k kl=l prjnm=v num=p cost=g arz=c clr=f chop=e cmpnm=a gh=j date=u pst=w zn=q pack=x ext=i prf=r bxknd=m tel=b percost=y move=o design=h
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table content has no column named tel (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO content(cel,ertefa,finalcost,tol,mn,gl,kl,prjnm,num,cost,arz,clr,chop,cmpnm,gh,date,pst,zn,pack,ext,prf,bxknd,tel,percost,move,design) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at so51893932.so51893932.ContentHelper.save(ContentHelper.java:44)
        at so51893932.so51893932.box_2_dtent$1.onClick(box_2_dtent.java:78)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The following version of ContentHelper.java should fix those errors (see comments) :-

```
public class ContentHelper {

    dbhelper dbhelper;
    public ContentHelper(Context context)
    {
        dbhelper = new dbhelper(context);
    }
    public Long save(content content)
    {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("cmpnm",content.cmpnm);
        contentValues.put("bxknd",content.bxknd);
        contentValues.put("tol",content.tol);
        contentValues.put("arz",content.arz);
        contentValues.put("ertefa",content.ertefa);
        contentValues.put("cost",content.cost);
        contentValues.put("num",content.num);
        contentValues.put("date",content.date);
        //contentValues.put("tel",content.tel); <<<< ERROR
        contentValues.put("tell",content.tel); //<<<< Corrected i.e. column name in table is tell not tel
        contentValues.put("design",content.design);
        contentValues.put("zn",content.zn);
        contentValues.put("pst",content.pst);
        contentValues.put("chop",content.chop);
        contentValues.put("gl",content.gl);
        contentValues.put("mn",content.mn);
        contentValues.put("gh",content.gh);
        contentValues.put("kl",content.kl);
        contentValues.put("pack",content.pack);
        contentValues.put("move",content.move);
        contentValues.put("ext",content.ext);
        contentValues.put("clr",content.clr);
        contentValues.put("cel",content.cel);
        //contentValues.put("profit",content.profit); //<<<< ERROR
        contentValues.put("prf",content.profit); //<<<< Corrected i.e. column name is prf not profit
        contentValues.put("finalcost",content.finalcost);
        contentValues.put("percost",content.percost);
        contentValues.put("prjnm",content.prjnm);

        dbhelper.opendb();
        Long a = dbhelper.db.insert(dbhelper.content,null,contentValues);
        dbhelper.closedb();
        return a;
    }
}
```

---

#### *Additional*

*It is far better to only rely on a single definition of table and column names (e.g. a suitably defined constant for each) rather than hard codes such names throughout your code (you've done this the table name by defining the table name in the dbhelper class and then reference it using dbhelper.content as per `Long a = dbhelper.db.insert(dbhelper.content,null,contentValues);`).*

Comment: **Thank you very much**